# Calculate number of buttons to add on UIScrollView by word length

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

What is the best way of creating those blocks or letters and for the letter holders like they did in here: (IconPopMania iOS app)

[image] [image]

What have I done so far? I've created the button part on the xib as `UIButton's` like that:

[image]

All the `UIButton's` are part of Outlet Collection:

`@IBOutlet var buttonCollection: [UIButton]!`

But for the answer part, I created a `UIScrollView` and draw a `UIButton's` on top of it with the correct clicked letter:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
button.setTitle(String(letter!), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.frame = CGRectMake(startDrawX, startDrawY, self.sizeOfButtonForAnswer.width, self.sizeOfButtonForAnswer.height)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.vAnswerScroller.addSubview(button)
```

What is my problem? I'm kinda stuck and need guidance, I don't know how to do the part of the letter holders, how to calculate the number of words and how many words can fit in one row, because there are answers with 1-2 and 3 words and each word is in a different length.. so i'm kinda confused.

Maybe there is another way to implement it? Maybe using UICollectionView or something like that?

I didn't use UICollectionView because when you click on a letter in the bottom section it has to disappear and appear in the upper part (in the first available place), but when you click on a letter on the upper part, it has to return to the place it were at start.

Comment: You should totally use a UICollectionView, IMO. Each square is a cell, when it is empty you just display an empty cell (not delete that cell), and that will give you the option to have dynamic word and letter size.

Comment: Why did you use a scroll view? Do you have multiple rows of buttons or just two?

Comment: In the upper letters container (the letters with the white background) could be more then 1 row of buttons, could be max 3 rows. I also need to know how to calculate how many rows I need to set and how to draw them.. I just don't know how to do it.